# xlsxwriter - Looping in value from database and storing in spreadsheet

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I have a table that stores column definition as listed below:

```
Col Name : store_name
Definition : name

Col Name : store_location
Definition : location
```

Table structure:

```
store_name,store_location
name,location
```

I am trying to have these values displayed in an excel spreadsheet using the below loop:

```
cursor = This queries the table that stores the above info
title_def = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]

row = 5
col = 2

for data in title_def:
    worksheet1.write(row, col, data, header_format)
    row += 1
```

The above loop only prints out the label. I am not sure how to modify the title_def above as I believe I am only filtering out the header and that gets displayed in the sheet using xlsxwriter. Could anyone advice how could I display both col_name and definition in the same spreadsheet..

Answer (score 0):

```
# Loop through cells in Excel and print values
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook('C:\\your_path\\ExcelFile.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.active
row_count = sheet.max_row
for i in range(row_count):
   print(sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value)


# And if you want to do the same with a CSV file
import csv
with open('C:\\your_path\\CSVFile.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```